# PostgreSQL FATAL: role "<USERNAME>" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate`, I get:

```
rake aborted!
FATAL:  role "<USERNAME>" does not exist
```

Note that

```
$ psql  --username=<USERNAME> --dbname=<DATABASE> --password
```

Does work - which is quite different than the similar questions here.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Odds are good your production configuration is not connecting to the same server as psql (your local server). Roles in Postgres are global, not database-specific.

Comment: @DanielLyons I double-checked even with `--host=localhost` (the same in database.yml). Could be two Postgres instances running on different ports ?!

Comment: Did you specify the port in database.yml? If so, try psql -p <portnum>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @DanielLyons for the head's up.

In fact, I was running two Postgres instances: one was being used by chef-server, on the default port 5432 and the "main one" on port 5433.

```
$ sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      571/postgres    
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5433          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10030/postgres
```

I just added to my databases.yml file:

```
port: 5433
```

And it worked.
(Note that this is a hotfix, until I get rid of the chef-server instance.)